# Why are Threads so much slower than Tasks in my code

Tags: c#, .net

I decided to learn more about threading and created a .NET 5 console application that uses 3 different ways to find all prime numbers from 2 to 100,000 and to compare how long they take to execute.

The `IsPrime` is used for determining if a number is a prime number and returns a `boolean` value

```
    private static bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        bool dividedByNotItself = false;

        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                dividedByNotItself = true;
            }
        }

        if (dividedByNotItself)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

My `Main` method calls the the three methods below

`FindPrimeSt` (single threaded)

```
    private static void FindPrimeSt(int from, int to)
    {
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        List<int> primeNumbers = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 2; i < to; i++)
        {
            if (IsPrime(i))
            {
                primeNumbers.Add(i);
            }
        }

        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeTaken = end - start;

        System.Console.WriteLine(
            $"FindPrimeSt found {primeNumbers.Count} prime numbers in {timeTaken.TotalSeconds}"
        );
    }
```

`FindPrimeUsingTasks`

```
    private static void FindPrimeUsingTasks(int from, int to)
    {
        List<int> primeNumbers = new List<int>();

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

        for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
        {
            int copyInt = i;

            tasks.Add(
                Task.Run(() => {return IsPrime(copyInt);})
            );

        }
        
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        foreach (Task<bool> task in tasks)
        {
            if (task.Result)
            {
                primeNumbers.Add(1);
            }
        }

        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeTaken = end - start;

        System.Console.WriteLine(
            $"FindPrimeUsingTasks found {primeNumbers.Count} prime numbers in {timeTaken.TotalSeconds}"
        );
    }
```

`FindPrimeUsingThreads`

```
    private static void FindPrimeUsingThreads(int from, int to)
    {
        List<int> primeNumbers = new List<int>();

        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = from; i < to; i++)
        {
            int copyInt = i;

            new Thread(() => {

                bool result = IsPrime(copyInt);

                if (result)
                {
                    primeNumbers.Add(i);
                }
            }).Start();
        }

        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeTaken = end - start;

        System.Console.WriteLine(
            $"FindPrimeUsingThreads found {primeNumbers.Count} prime numbers in {timeTaken.TotalSeconds}"
        );
    }
```

This is the output of the program

`FindPrimeSt found 9592 prime numbers in 19.4423727 seconds`

`FindPrimeUsingTasks found 9592 prime numbers in 6.2772479 seconds`

`FindPrimeUsingThreads found 9592 prime numbers in 72.4205661 seconds`

Now, `FindPrimeUsingThreads` is quite a lot slower than `FindPrimeUsingTasks`. Is all of that down to the overhead for creating the threads and Tasks taking advantage of the threadpool?

Sneaky side question:
Is using `List<T>.Add()` in `FindPrimeUsingThreads` or `FindPrimeUsingTasks` thread-safe, or should I create a wrapper function with a lock?

Thank you.

Comment: You're creating a new thread for each computation, which has its own overhead. Try with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` too.

Comment: Creating new threads has overheads, and too many threads will cause 'cpu churn' as it tries to maintain the timeshare.  Tasks use a pre-allocated thread pool and are scheduled to pool threads as the thread becomes available, sometimes allowing a new task to start immediately after a previous task has ended before the thread is preempted.

Comment: Outside the arguments above, you should be using benchmarkdotnet for accurate measurements.

Comment: It's most likely the comments above are accurate, and that the bulk of the difference comes from the fact that you create so many threads, creating an enormous amount of contention for the CPU, while the thread pool generally will automatically and most efficiently make use of _available_ CPU cores. Ironically, your thread-based version is probably much _faster_ than it really should be, because you fail to synchronize access to the list; doing so will add even more contention, but at least will avoid corrupting the list data structure like you're doing now.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Hiow would one achieve the list access synchronisation? Via a lock?

Comment: There are lots of synchronization mechanisms available to you. The `lock` statement is perhaps one of the simplest to use and understand. There are also thread-safe collection types (e.g. `ConcurrentBag<T>`). Some research should reveal a wide array of options to you.